# Rust - Converting from `&str` to `String` and back with Closures

Tags: rust, closures, borrow-checker, ownership, borrowing

I'm working through the [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-03-improving-our-io-project.html) and I'm not understanding why this function doesn't compile:

```rust
pub fn search<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    contents
        .lines()                           // Fetch an iterator for each line in `contents`
        .map(|x| x.to_lowercase())         // (x is now String) Convert each line to lowercase
        .filter(|x| x.contains(query))     // Filter out lines that do not contain query
        .map(|x| x.trim())                 // Eliminate extra whitespace
        .collect()                         // Consume iterator and produce Vec<&str>
}
```

Without the `to_lowercase()` line it will run, and I'm guessing that is because that will return a `String` instead of the `&str` we'll need to output at the end. However when I either substitute a conversion back to `&str` like:

```
// -- snip --
.map(|x| x.to_lowercase().to_str())
// -- snip --
```

This states that a temporary value is being referenced. Which I assume because `&str` reference the `String`, when the `String` is released it makes my `&str` invalid as well.

Are closures just not a good way of handling this, and I should break it into different statement?

Comment: Do the end results need to be lowercased? Or is that only needed for the query matching?

Comment: Oh that's a good point. In my case I want to leave contents alone, and just use it for query matching. I would be interested in the answer for either direction though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This states that a temporary value is being referenced. Which I assume because `&str` reference the `String`, when the `String` is released it makes my `&str` invalid as well.

This assumption is correct.

> Are closures just not a good way of handling this, and I should break it into different statement?

No amount of refactoring that function will change the fact that `to_lowercase()` requires modifying the `&str` and has to produce a `String`, so if lowercasing the contents is a requirement then this is the best you can do:

```rust
fn search(query: &str, contents: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    contents
        .lines()                           // Fetch an iterator for each line in contents
        .map(|x| x.trim().to_lowercase())  // Trim & lowercase string
        .filter(|x| x.contains(query))     // Filter out lines that do not contain query
        .collect()                         // Consume iterator and produce Vec<String>
}
```

If you want to perform case-insensitive filtering but still return the unmodified contents (no lowercasing) then you can do this:

```rust
fn search<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    contents
        .lines()                                        // Fetch an iterator for each line in contents
        .filter(|x| x.to_lowercase().contains(query))   // Filter out lines that do not contain query
        .map(|x| x.trim())                              // Trim whitesapce
        .collect()                                      // Consume iterator and produce Vec<&'a str>
}
```

Comment: Interesting, so either a) switch to a `vec<String>` because I require modifications to the contents (e.g. lowercase) or b) chain lowercase() and contains()  which will return a bool and not a reference to the string which immediately would get released.

Comment: The lifetime is needed because the Vec will only be valid while contents still exists.

Comment: @Gates Yup, you got it!

Answer (score 1):

For the person that follows behind me, here's where I ended up. Thanks @pretzelhammer.

```rust
pub fn search_case_insensitive<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let query = query.to_lowercase(); // transform query to lowercase()
    contents
        .lines() 
        .filter(|x| x.to_lowercase().contains(&query))
        .map(|x| x.trim())
        .collect()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just my two cents as I was dealing with that question recently too and I wish I had that kind of explanation earlier:

Why this does not work:

```
pub fn search<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    contents
        .lines()                           // Fetch an iterator for each line in `contents`
        .map(|x| x.to_lowercase())         // (x is now String) Convert each line to lowercase
        .filter(|x| x.contains(query))     // Filter out lines that do not contain query
        .map(|x| x.trim())                 // Eliminate extra whitespace
        .collect()                         // Consume iterator and produce Vec<&str>
}
```

is because the function expects to return `Vec<&'a str>` but during the chain of events we apply `to_lowercase()` function within `map` which changes all elements in the `Vec` to `String`. No matter what kind of other operations we do - this one creates new values of different type.

Now, why this works

```
pub fn search_case_insensitive<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let query = query.to_lowercase(); // transform query to lowercase()
    contents
        .lines() 
        .filter(|x| x.to_lowercase().contains(&query))
        .map(|x| x.trim())
        .collect()
}
```

It's because during the chain of operations on the iterator there is NO TYPE CHANGE and there is no new value created.

The part `filter(|x| x.to_lowercase().contains(&query))` is crucial. This function is expected to filter elements from the collection which do not pass the test condition within the closure. We can see that we call `to_lowercase()` within, but that changes only the argument of the closure to `String`. We can safely call `contains(&query)` here which is `String` in this case as well.

`contains` returns `true` or `false` and based on that `filter` knows what element of `contents.lines()` collection (which still is `&str`) to drop. Therefore - we end up with collection of `&str` elements without making any changes to those elements.

Side comment - `lines()` in theory returns `Lines<'_>` which (per documentation) is `An iterator over the lines of a string, as string slices.`. So we're all good here.